# Use of libcrypto.so.0.9.7

Tags: solaris

Can anyone point out the use of libcrypto.so.0.9.7 in solaris?

I know it is used for SSH.

Answer (score 2):

libcrypto is part of [OpenSSL](http://openssl.org/), so it could be used by any program that need cryptographic service (SSH, Apache if you use SSL, ...)